# Compiling subset of tests in Google Test

Tags: googletest, compilation-time

Using flags to limit the tests run in [Google Test framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) is great, but in my case most of the time is wasted on waiting for the entire test project to compile again and again while I'm writing tests.

Is there an easy way to limit the compilation to just those test cases I'm currently working on?

(Removing the test cpp files and resource cpp files from VS is always an alternative, but it's a lot of work...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always split your tests to different projects (perhaps under the same solution in Visual Studio) thus building an executable per group of test cases